# Vaadin UI.access() throws ExecutionException

Tags: java, session, exception, vaadin, vaadin7

I see this exception in Vaadin project. However, functionality does not really break. The code in `run()` method does what it is intented to complete, but this exception appears.

```
E 140619 124701.131 [Thread-2] MainUI - Uncaught throwable: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession$FutureAccess.get(VaadinSession.java:123)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:1802)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.unlock(VaadinSession.java:1012)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.ensureAccessQueuePurged(VaadinService.java:1763)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.accessSession(VaadinService.java:1729)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.access(VaadinSession.java:1402)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.access(UI.java:1372)
```

happens here

```
ui.acccess(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code here
    }
}
```

What I am supposed to do? Can I just catch exception and ignore it or somewhere there is a bug in my code?

It uses @Push annotation for MainUI extends UI and there is code like:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    WrappedSession wrappedSession = request.getWrappedSession();
    final String id = wrappedSession.getId();
    log.info("Created new UI for session id {}", id);

    VaadinSession.getCurrent().setErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void error(com.vaadin.server.ErrorEvent event) {
            super.error(event);
            log.error("Uncaught throwable: ", event.getThrowable());
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

## Another Example

[This section added by a different author]

I, Basil Bourque, am getting what seems to be the same exception in the same usage. The exception is thrown in production use (not development).

Using Vaadin 7.1.3 with Push with Tomcat 8.0.12 on Java 8 Update 20 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Exception:

```
Nov 04, 2014 4:45:50 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession$FutureAccess.get(VaadinSession.java:123)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:1800)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.unlock(VaadinSession.java:1013)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.ensureAccessQueuePurged(VaadinService.java:1761)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.accessSession(VaadinService.java:1727)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.access(VaadinSession.java:1403)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.access(UI.java:1389)
    at com.rainwatersoft.powerwrangler.curr_sup_dem.CurrSupDemReportUpdater.update(CurrSupDemReportUpdater.java:164)
    at com.rainwatersoft.powerwrangler.curr_sup_dem.CurrSupDemReportUpdater.checkForUpdate(CurrSupDemReportUpdater.java:125)
    at com.rainwatersoft.powerwrangler.curr_sup_dem.CurrSupDemReportUpdater.lambda$considerUpdate$2(CurrSupDemReportUpdater.java:110)
    at com.rainwatersoft.powerwrangler.curr_sup_dem.CurrSupDemReportUpdater$$Lambda$3/1011224121.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The offending code is using the Lambda syntax of Java 8 to pass a Runnable to the [UI::access](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

```
layout.getUI().access( () -> { // Runnable
    layout.freshen( this.interval );
} );
```

Comment: I find it strange that there is a NPE in the session management. Are you using server push in some sort?

Comment: What do you mean by server push?

Comment: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html

Comment: yes, `@Push public class MainUI extends UI {`

Comment: Are you using vaadin 7.2.0? There have been a lot of fixes in the push area

Comment: Have you debugged the vaadin-server source code and checked what is causing the NullPointerException?

Comment: Please post the complete code which invokes the `ui.access()` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is excerpt from my code:

```
// remember UI and request attributes
val ui = UI.getCurrent
val attributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes

future.onSuccess {
  case e => ui.access(
    new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        try {
          RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes)
          success.apply(e)
        } finally {
          RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes()
        }
      }
    }
  )
}

future.onFailure {
  case t => ui.access(
    new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        try {
          _logger.error("Something goes wrong in async await request", t)
          RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes)
          failure.apply(t)
        } finally {
          RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes()
        }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

I'm using spring4vaadin with the latest Vaadin 7.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to run the application in jvm with -ea parameter in order to enable assertions. Usually this exception is thrown because of faulty code elsewhere. I.e. your ui.access(..) is most likely correct, but some other piece of code is actually locking the UI and hence exception is thrown.